# Offer more options for tag subscription digests

Tags: feature-request, tags, subscription

While subscribing to tags, it shows digest mail duration set to one day. If it is weekly digest (or, for that matter, any customizable days) it will be great.

Please consider changing duration to be customizable.

Answer (score 2):

This is already possible, via [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/42653/kumar?tab=subscriptions):

> [image]

(no worry,  that's a screenshot from my profile - I can only see "subscribe" on your filters, and can't manage them myself)